# How can i make constructor without fields with enum?

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I don't have idea how to add to array enum. I made constructor using fields with enum and its works, but I don't know how to make it in constructor without field. I hope that you understand what Im thinking about. In my code I comment where I think i have problem. 
I've got:

```
public enum Components {
    WIFI, BLUETOOTH, CAMERA, SSD
}

public Laptop(){
    System.out.println("name of producer:");
    String producername = Main.sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("name of model:");
    String modelname = Main.sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("ram:");
    int ram = Main.sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cpu:");
    String cpu = Main.sc.nextLine();
    cpu = Main.sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("components:");
    System.out.println("how many components do you want to add?");
    int z = Main.sc.nextInt();
    Components[] com = new Components[z];
    for(int i=0; i<com.length;i++){
        com[i] = //<-- how to add enum in array?
    }

    setProducerName(producername);
    setModelName(modelname);
    setRam(ram);
    setCpu(cpu);
    setComponents(com);
}
```

My constructor using field is like that and it works.

```
    public Laptop(String ProducerName, String ModelName, int Ram, String Cpu, Components... components) {
    super();
    this.ProducerName= ProducerName;
    this.ModelName= ModelName;
    this.Ram= Ram;
    this.Cpu= Cpu;
    this.components= new Components[components.length];
    this.components= Arrays.copyOf(components, components.length);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `enum` value by its name.

```
public enum Components {
    WIFI, BLUETOOTH, CAMERA, SSD
}

public Laptop(){
    ...
    Components[] com = new Components[z];
    for(int i=0; i<com.length;i++){
        com[i] = Components.valueOf(Main.sc.nextLine());
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear what you're asking, but you can get an array filled with your enum constants from the enum itself: `Components.values()` will return an array of **all** the enum constants. It will essentially return:

```
new Components[]{Components.WIFI, Components.BLUETOOTH, 
    Components.CAMERA, Components.SSD}
```

Side recommendation: don't use Scanner inside of your Laptop constructor, and in fact, get all user interface code out of all constructors and instance methods of that class. All user interface code belongs elsewhere.